# How to calculate the SDCM?

Tags: color

I have a light source that I want to know value for SDCM for it ( Standard Deviation Color Matching ) .

I've been searching for hours with no clear way for it .

I have the CCT , (x,y) coordinates , (u,v) ,(u',v') , and Duv .

is there a formula or a way to calculate the SDCM ?

Hope I'm asking the the question in the right place, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In short: You need to compare your u'v' data with the nominal u'v'_nom data of different nominal CCTs (based on IEC 60881). With the euclidean distance in u'v' colour space between u'v' and u'v'_nom, you can determine the SDCM.

You can find a better and detailed description in:

https://www.ee.co.za/article/chromaticity-difference-specification-for-light-sources.html

Tip:
SDCM = n in formula (2)